# Define a subset of Racket

Tags: lisp, racket

Since Racket is well-known for his ability to create new programming language, the following shouldn't be too difficult.

I would like to create a subset of Racket (let's name it `min`) for an educational purpose renaming some function (`tail` instead of `cdr`) and ignoring others (such as `string=?` and `=` to just have `equal?`).

The first step I made is to start my `min` files with `#lang s-exp "min.rkt"` but I am stuck at the expander stage.

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074984/defining-a-purely-functional-r5rs-env-in-racket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following module is an example of a minimal subset of Racket that allows top-level definitions, constants, and arithmetic using `+` and `*`:

```
;; min.rkt
#lang racket/base
(provide #%module-begin #%top-interaction
         #%app #%datum #%top
         define + *)
```

Here's what the provides mean:

- `#%module-begin` *must* be provided by a module for that module to be considered a "language"; it determines what a module body means. You can just reuse Racket's module-begin macro. (The `#%module-begin` export gives you a hook to implement *non-local* constraints or transformations. For example, if you wanted to add a typechecker or check that variables are defined in alphabetical order, you could do that in the module-begin hook.)
- `#%top-level` is necessary for interactive languages. If you leave it out, you can't use a REPL for your language (eg, with `racket -t "min.rkt" -i`).
- `#%app` and `#%datum` make function application and self-evaluating constants (like numbers and booleans) work.
- `#%top` makes forward references work at the REPL, like in mutually-recursive functions. You still must define a name before you *evaluate* a reference to it, of course.
- The rest of the exports are the special forms and functions you want to include in your language.

Here's a program in this `"min.rkt"` language:

```
#lang s-exp "min.rkt"
(define x 2)
(define y (+ x 5))
(* y 7)
(define (f x) (+ x x 1))
(f 8)
```

Note that since the language includes Racket's `define`, it allows function definition, even though the language doesn't include `lambda`. If you wanted a restricted version of `define`, you would have to define your own macro and provide it as your language's `define`, like `(provide (rename-out [my-define define]))`.

You can also use `rename-out` to provide Racket's `cdr` as `tail`, but the procedure would still print as `#<procedure:cdr>` and if it raised an error the error message would still say `cdr`. To change that, you'd need to define your own wrapper function that does its own error checking.